# Fixing resizing issue in BorderLayout. Either the buttons move or dont show

Tags: border-layout

I need to make a GUI interface (using BorderLayout) that looks like the image attached.(https://i.stack.imgur.com/0C7RY.jpg) 
the issue is that I am not allowed to restrict resizing and the buttons can not move to another row. I have the code working to display the proper image I dont know how to make it show the buttons without resizing and without the buttons moving. Any suggestions would be truly helpful

```
import java.awt.*; 
import javax.swing.*;
class MyComponents extends JFrame{
MyComponents (String title){
  JFrame frame = new JFrame(title);
  frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

  BorderLayout layout = new BorderLayout(2,3);
  frame.setLayout(layout);


  JPanel northPanel = new JPanel();
    //JPanel westPanel = new JPanel();
  JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel();
    //JPanel eastPanel = new JPanel();

  JTextField Text = new JTextField();
  northPanel.add(new JLabel("Current Value:"));
  northPanel.add(Text);
  Text.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50,24));


  centerPanel.add(new JButton("+"));
  centerPanel.add(new JButton("-"));
  centerPanel.add(new JButton("Reset"));
  centerPanel.add(new JButton("Quit"));

  frame.add(northPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
  frame.add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
  frame.setVisible(true);

   }
}
public class Homework7b {
   public static void main (String [] args)
   {
      MyComponents Homework7b = new MyComponents("Part 02 Using getSource");





   }

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by icons?

Comment: @JanTojnar, sorry I meant the buttons

Comment: trying adding one panel with a borderlayout instead of your frame use setLayout(null) on the frame and create a new borderlayout when initializing the panel.                                                        bgPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout(2,3));
frame.setLayout(null);